# How do I connect to my Google cloud SQL instance with C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use visual studio to write a program in c# and have it connect to my google cloud sql server. Unfortunately I have been trying to troubleshoot it and have had no luck. I already added my IP and my connection works through MYSQL Workbench.

I attempted to connect with the whole data source, network library, initial catalog, etc. I tried it without the network library and used the proper way to escape \ in the string during the connection. I also tried the default 1433 port and 3306. No luck.

```
 // Build Connection String
            SqlConnection clearviscon = new SqlConnection(@"Server=xx.xx.xx.xx\alpine-park-243102:us-central1:xxx, 3306;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=xxdatabase;User ID=root;Password=xxx123");
            clearviscon.Open();
```

Comment: If you are really using MySQL you are using the wrong DB Provider.  `SqlConnection` is for Microsoft SQL Server which is completely different from MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to Google Cloud SQL for MySQL, you must use a MySQL client library. I recommend [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/).

Your connection string will be `Server=xx.xx.xx.xx;Database=xxdatabase;User ID=root;Password=xxx123`.

If you're using a [client SSL certificate](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance#new-client) to connect to your server, add this to the end of your connection string: `;SslCa=server-ca.pem;SslCert=client-cert.pem;SslKey=client-key.pem`.

Answer (score 0):

You must use MySqlConnection.

See this link for more information: https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/using-cloud-sql